# Where is the datatable in angular with nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I know the listview exists but it has no columnheader.

I could not find any information about a datatable using angular with nativescript:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/rich-components

Answer (score 1):

There is one directive called **tkListViewHeader**
For example if your listview item template e.g.( `<ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item" let-i="index">`) has GridLayout View with 5 columns then you can write your header temple code with Same GridLayout.

```
<ng-template tkListViewHeader>

                        <GridLayout width="100%" columns="3*,2.5*,1.5*,1.5*,2*" orientation="horizontal" >

                            <Label col="0" text="Customer" class="header-text" [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': 20}"></Label>
                            <Label col="1" text="Order" class="header-text-center"></Label>
                            <Label col="2" text="Qty" class="header-text-center"></Label>
                            <Label col="3" text="Load" class="header-text"></Label>
                            <Label col="4" text="Status" class="header-text-center" [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': 20}"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>

                    </ng-template>
```